# Firestore where function on react with date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function set up which queries my firestore database and shows the relevant information.

It works for all of the fields in the document except for the date.

What I am trying to do is show the documents which have a date beyond the current date.

The date in the firestore documents displays like this: yyyy-mm-dd. I have the date showing up in the same format but it doesn't filter the documents at all.

The where query is set up as follows:

```
const courseCollectionRef = collection(Firestoredb, collectionId)
const q = query(courseCollectionRef, where('visitDate', '>', currentDate), orderBy('visitDate'))
```

The current date is determined by the following code:

```
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  var date = new Date().getDate()
  var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1
  var year = new Date().getFullYear()
  setCurrentDate(
    year + '-' + '0' + month + '-' + date
  )
}, [])
```

Picture for reference: I expected the boxes in the first column not to show but the other boxes to still show.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of document that you think should be returned in this query? Also have you tried storing date as Timestamp instead of string? Also `'0' + month` would be `012` in case of December and not just `12`?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the post. I expected the boxes in the first column not to be returned, but the others to show. I didn't try storing it as a timestamp, the data comes in through a react form with an input type of 'date'. Would there be a way to select a specific date on the form and return it as a timestamp to firebase?

Comment: Do you mean you got the date from Firestore but it didn’t work the way you need in React?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the date comes in from firestore, but when I do a query to show only dates after the current date it doesn't work. Other querys with the same firestore collection work perfectly, just the date query that I'm having problems with.